# WatchKit : How do I add an image that overlaps the navigation bar (if it is possible)?

Tags: objective-c, image, swift, watchkit

As you can see from the image below, the static interface notification controller is able to have an image overlap the navigation bar a little.
However, when I try this in a regular interface controller I am unsuccessful sadly. It automatically puts my image below the navigation bar. Is there a way around this? If so, please let me know. Any tips or suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to overlap the navigation bar in the current version of WatchKit. The over/underlap that you're seeing is exclusive to the notification interface controller.